# write to xterm process programmatically using Java

Tags: java, processbuilder, xterm

Is there anyway to read and write data to the xterm console?
I mean using `ProcessBuilder` class, we can invoke external process, and e.g using `cmd \c` or `bash` one can write and read data to system console.

Now I have a virtual machine console which consists further embedded virtual machines. From the root console i open xterm consoles and I am wondering is it possible to write data pragmatically to those consoles?

This might be more likely an xterm cmd line option question, but I can't find any information, any suggestions, or this is simply not possible.

**EDIT:**

Explanation:

@MarcB, yes I am not interested in the graphical wrapper rather need to write/read to the tty device. Now my issue is i access bash, and from using xterm proc1 proc2 i open two xterm consoles while the main root console is blocked until these two xterm windows are terminated. In my case, now once i have access to root console, then how from there i can further invoke simultaneous two (xterm console like) processes? I mean i can open two separate root consoles and then do this thing, but unfortunately in my case this is not possible.

Comment: xterms should have a matching /dev/stty device you could write to, assuming everything's running under the same uid.

Comment: @MarcB, can you give me some idea how to get hold of this programatically??

Comment: the tty devices are just files, like any other. once you figure out which file /dev matches the xterm/tty you want to write to, you just use standard file operations to do so (fopen/fwrite/etc...).

Comment: When you say 'xterm' do you mean xterm specifically (the terminal emulator in X Windows) or do you just mean a way of communicating with a remote process via the command line?

Comment: xterm is just a graphical wrapper around a standard shell, which is a wrapper around a tty device.